# Start any file (Not exe) in Hidden Mode using C#

Tags: c#

I am having a requirement to Start/Open any file (saved in disk) in hidden mode.
Example: "C:\abc.txt","C:\abc.xlsx"...

I have used below code but it did't work.

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = "excel.exe";
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            startInfo.Arguments = @"C:\abc.xlsx";
            Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Is there any way to open any type of **FILE** in hidden mode?

Comment: What you meant by `hidden mode?` open as minimized?

Comment: You don't "start" a file, you (inherently) start the associated executable with the filename as argument (or through DDE). Please explain what you actually mean.

Comment: I don't know why you don't see any research effect on the question I have raised. 
Well, I have a windows service and I want to open saved excel workbook customization in hidden mode. Currently I am doing this action via Excel Interop assembly (ie: VSTO). But Microsoft doesn't suggest Office Automation from windows service. Therefore I want start a saved file as a hidden process and do further processing inside the work book customization

Answer (score 0):

To open a document which has an executable registered for its file type you set UseShellExecute = true. I don't know if it works with the  ProcessWindowStyleHidden WindowStyle flag though. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute(v=vs.110).aspx